# Multiple use of grep command

Tags: grep

Can anyone tell what this line actually mean?? Here the grep command is used multiple times.

```
#chkCount=`ps -aef | grep -i "File_Transfer.sh"|grep -v grep| wc -l`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down piece by piece.  First of all the command is commented out so it won't run until you remove the starting `#`

```
chkCount=`ps -aef | grep -i "File_Transfer.sh"|grep -v grep| wc -l`
```

The output of the command `ps -aef | grep -i "File_Transfer.sh"|grep -v grep| wc -l` will be stored in the variable `chkCount`.

`grep -i "File_Transfer.sh"` looks for lines containing "File_Transfer.sh" but grep will ignore the case of the string.  That means that grep will match "File_Transfer.sh", "File_TRANSFER.SH", or any other combination.

`grep -v grep` will match any line that DOESN'T contain the word `grep`.  `-v` inverts the match.  The purpose of this is to eliminate the command you issued.  In other words `ps` will list a process called `File_Transer.sh` and it will list your command  `ps -aef | grep -i "File_Transfer.sh"|grep -v grep| wc -l`.  `grep -v` will ignore `ps -aef | grep -i "File_Transfer.sh"|grep -v grep| wc -l` and just match any process matching `File_Transfer.sh`

Lastly, `wc -l` will count the number of lines fed into `wc`.  So the result will be the number of processes running that matches "File_Transfer.sh"

Answer (score 0):

This line lists all running processes and filters lines that include "File_Transfer.sh".

The output is then further filtered to remove lines that include "grep", since the grep command itself will show up as a running process with the text "File_Transfer.sh".

wc -l counts how many lines found.

Comment: Thanks for answer.....can you also help me with below line--

if test $# = 1 && test -e $1

Answer (score 0):

Multiple use of grep (in a piped combination like this) is like a two-stage filter; whatever lines are passed from the first instance will be filtered again according to the second instance's arguments.  In this case, the result of `ps -aef` is piped to grep, which does a case-insensitive search for "File_Transfer.sh"; then all the lines output by grep are fed to grep again, which passes all lines that don't contain `grep` (-v means "invert match", look for what doesn't match, rather than what does) to wc -- at the end, the final result (a count of occurrences) is assigned to variable chkCount.